# HTML Forms two actions

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect, action

So generally I have a form whose action is a link that verifies the user's username and password (can't post the link does not belong to me) and if it's correct it gives me an  "ok" or else a "no"
How can I make it in a way that if yes it directs me to my index page and if no gives an error or reloads the page or something. Is their a way to do that
the general html appearance is:

```
 <form method="post" action="https://***************/login">
        <label for="book">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        <label for="course">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
```

so if I were to change it into the way I want it then the action should change into something like verify.php which would have the appearance of

```
<?php
    # how do I use an if for a link using the info that was input
    if($_POST["https://***************/login"]){
         #load index.html
 ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.location.href = 'index.html';
        </script>
<?php
    else{ 
        #load the page again
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.location.href = 'login.php';
        </script>
<?php        
     }
?>
```

I'm a bit new to php.
So please help

Comment: I recommend you have the form post back to itself. If there are errors, show the form again with those errors. If everything is okay, then do you login logic (add the user to the session or whatever) and then redirect the user to a success page.

Comment: when you say the login action link isn't yours do you mean you have no access to edit that verification file either?

Comment: @FabioG yes i don't have access to edit the verification file

Comment: in that case I think your best option is to submit the form via ajax and then redirecting or handle the error using javascript depending on the answer you recieve from login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unable to edit the login verification file, I think your best option is to submit the form via ajax and handle its response with javascript, having your form like

```
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label for="book">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
    <label for="course">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" onclick="btnAuthenticateUser();">
</form>
```

then, in plain javascript something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp;
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    try {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
function btnAuthenticateUser() {
    try {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        var pwd = document.getElementById('password');
        xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
        if (xmlHttp == null) {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return;
        }
        var url = 'https://***************/login?username=' + username.value + '&password=' + pwd.value;
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    if (xmlHttp.responseText == "ok") {
                        window.location = "index.html"; 
                    } else {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                    // LoadingPage
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 1) {
            //LoadingPage
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.Message);
    }
}
</script>
```

or if you're using jQuery

```
function btnAuthenticateUser() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'https://***************/login', 
        data: { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()} 
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (data == "ok") {
            window.location = "index.html";
        }else{
            location.reload();
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
         GriterError(Global.FailTryAgain);
    });
}
```

Comment: if i use the javascript code then it gives me an error at line 79 that has xmlHttp.send(null); with an error of net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED if i use the jquery it does not enter if(data == "ok") it directly reloads the page even if the input was corect

Comment: never mind got it running by adding a header and like removing ' =="ok" '

Answer (score 3):

There is a header to redirect, you have to put it in your php script :

```
header('Location: yoururl.com');
```

To record error from your script, you can set it in $_SESSION variables :

```
session_start(); // at the beginning of your script
$_SESSION['error'] = 'Password incorrect, please try again';
```

And so, in your other page, you can use something like :

```
if($_SESSION['error']) {
    echo $_SESSION['error']; // display error
    $_SESSION['error'] = ''; // delete it 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the action you need on your verification script and then throw in a redirect using the headers in PHP.

After the verification action you can choose which page to go to through an if/then statement

for example:

```
if ([the action you wanted succeeded]) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```